# How to prove a function is a regular Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

We have a function $w: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ which obeys the following property:
$$
\sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (-b, +b)} w(r) < \infty, \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 < b < \infty
$$

for $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, define the function $\mu(E) = 0$, if $E = \emptyset$ and
$$\mu(E) = \sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap E} w(r), \ \ \ \ \ \ E \neq \emptyset.$$

How do I prove that $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

I tried to relate the measure defined here with the Lebesgue-Stiletjes measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then from that conclude somehow that the function defined above is regular.

P.S: a regular Borel measure satisfies the following:

if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and given $\epsilon > 0$, then there is an open set $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, such that:

1. $A \subseteq G$.
2. $\mu\left( G \setminus A \right) < \epsilon$.

This is a homework question, I am not asking for solutions, just for hints.

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mu(E)=\sum_{r \in \Bbb{Q}}w(r)\delta_q(E)$ is defined on the powerset of $\Bbb{R}$.

Here $\delta_q$ denotes the Dirac measure.

It is true that if $\mu_n$ is a sequence of measures on a sigma algebra then $\sum_n\mu_n$ is also a measure.(A good exercise for you).From this, by taking an enumeration of the rationals,you can deduce that $\mu$ is a measure,

Since it is defined on the powerset then it is defined on every Borel set.

Now from hypothesis,the Borel measure $\mu$ is locally finite on $\Bbb{R}$,thus regular.

A reference for that can be found at: [http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/](http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/%7Epapadim/)

In the measure theory lecture notes(go to course notes),on page 64,theorem 5.7

Theorem 5.7 is a  general theorem for regularity of Borel measures on a topological space.

It would be quite instructive to read its proof ,becuase uses techniques that you will encounter often in measure theory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, definitely a thing to check out. However, we are still at the beginning of the course and what the notes mentioned are out of the scope of what we have taken so far. In any case, the "dream" open set containing any measurable E should be $(-b, b)$ (assuming E is bounded by $b$). 
however the difference is not quite small. How do we incorporate $\epsilon$ and make the set different $\mu \left[ (-b, b) \setminus E \right] < \epsilon$ ?
Thank you again.